# Ajax call does not activate callback function

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript

I'm struggling with this for a couple of days already, so any help is most welcome.
Not my first time setting up Ajax with WP, so I have some idea at the least.
It concerns a very standard form validation and inputting info to database. **This all inside of a plugin.**

So, what works: form submission works, the jquery script is activated and forwards the input info to the callback PHP file.

Problem is that, for some reason, the specific function that handles the form on that PHP file is not activated.

So, what do I have? I will skip the form as such because it seems pretty standard.

1 - the javascript/jquery

> /plugins/alert-widget/submit_handler.js

```
jQuery(document).ready( function() {

jQuery("#alert_set_form").on("submit", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var info = jQuery("#alert_set_form").serialize();
    // Post to the server
    jQuery.ajax({       
        type:"POST",
        url:ajaxAlert.ajaxurl,
        data:info,
        dataType:'json',
        success: function(data){
             jQuery("#alert_set_form .stm-validation-message").html(data);
        }
    });
});
});
```

1- the main PHP plugin file that builds the form and is supposed to handle the validation/data input.

> /plugins/alert-widget/alert_widget.php

```
add_action('wp_ajax_bda_alert', 'bda_alert_validation');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_bda_alert', 'bda_alert_validation');

/* this commented out code was placed just to check if call hits the file, which it does

if( isset($_POST['model'])){
                $criteria = array(
                              'model' => $_POST['model'],
                              'body' => $_POST['body'],
                              'price' => $_POST['price'],
                              'mileage' => $_POST['mileage'],
                              'ca-year' => $_POST['ca-year'],
                              'fuel' => $_POST['fuel'],
                              'transmission' => $_POST['transmission']
                              );

            $criteria = base64_encode(serialize($criteria));
            $response = $criteria;
            wp_send_json( $response );
            wp_die();
        }
*/
    function bda_alert_validation(){
     //does validation and input 

            $response =array(
                'data'  => 'success',
                'supplemental' => array(
                    'message' => 'success',
                ),
            ) ;

            wp_send_json( $response );
            wp_die();       
    }



add_action('init', 'alert_form_init' );

function alert_form_init() {
wp_register_script( "alert_form_script", WP_PLUGIN_URL.'/alert-widget/submit_handler.js', array('jquery') );
wp_localize_script( 'alert_form_script', 'ajaxAlert', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' )));

wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
wp_enqueue_script( 'alert_form_script');

}
```

Comment: Have you considered using a REST API endpoint instead? It's easier to work with and secure

Comment: Thanks @TomJNowell. Not even aware of the possibility. Can you elaborate?

Comment: There's a REST API at `/wp-json`, look up `register_rest_route`, e.g. https://tomjn.com/2017/01/23/writing-wp-rest-api-endpoint-2-minutes/

Comment: Is `action` passed with your form data?

Comment: @Milo, you may be on to something. How should I include the form action. Like   <form id="alert_set_form" name="alert_set_form" action="/admin-ajax.php?action=bda_alert_validation" > ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you're serializing the form, as ajax data, you could be missing the `action` part from your form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="action" value="bda_alert">
```

so your ajax request would contain

```
/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=bda_alert&...
```

that should invoke the `wp_ajax_bda_alert` or `wp_ajax_nopriv_bda_alert` action callback.

Comment: That was it, thanks. I wasn't aware of that at all and the literature around it did not help either. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

The above AJAX callback could be rewritten as a REST API endpoint like this:

```
function bda_alert_validation( $request ){
    // $info = $request['info'];
    $response = array(
        'data'  => 'success',
        'supplemental' => array(
            'message' => 'success'
        )
    ) ;
    return $response;      
}

add_action( 'rest_api_init', function () {
        register_rest_route( 'bernarda/v1', '/validatealert/', array(
                'methods' => 'POST',
                'callback' => 'bda_alert_validation'
        ) );
} );
```

Now you have an endpoint at `example.com/wp-json/benarda/v1/validatealert/` that you can do `POST` requests against

Comment: I'm reading thru some material on this. How should I set up the jquery?

Comment: exactly the same, just use the REST API endpoint URL instead

Comment: thanks for showing me this alternative way. I will look further into it. For now though, birgire found what the issue was and I should accept his answer.

Comment: Tom i think you need an script to add `Have you considered using a REST API endpoint instead?` automatically to every question that has an `admin-ajax` tag ;)

Comment: @JackJohansson anything less is unethical